# How to initialize string variables in java console program?

Tags: java, console-application

This is about a java console program in which there are some string variables which are used to search records and display in the console.
When i execute this program there comes the error message:

> error: variable "variable name" might not have been initialized.

I want to know how i can initialize string variables in java console program. Here is the code:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String customername;String cname;
String caddress;String cphone
boolean found;
System.out.println("Enter customer name to search records:");
customername=sc.nextLine();
if (customername==cname)
{
  found=true;
  if(found){
    System.out.println("Customer name:"+cname);
    System.out.println("Customer address:"+caddress);
    System.out.println("Customer phone:"+cphone);}
  }
}
```

Here i want to search records saved in a text file and display records if `cname==customername` but error tells that string variable `cname` it is not initialized and also for `caddress` and `cphone`.
What should i do to initialize string variables and how to do this?

Comment: You initialize variables by assigning values to them. Like: `String someVariable = "initialValue";` In Java, it is an error to try to read a local variable before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: thanks for the answer.The problem has been solved now.thanks

Comment: Also note that you should never use == to compare strings. Call the equals method instead.

Comment: And your whole code there, to first compare, then assign a value to that boolean to then immediately afterwards check that boolean value, that is nonsensical.

Comment: Finally: you accept answers by clicking on that check mark icon next to it. Writing a comment "I accept the answer" isn't what that other person really cares about...

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have a default value then you can initialize your string variables to empty strings as below.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String customername = "";
String cname = "";
String caddress = "";
String cphone  = "";
boolean found = false;

System.out.println("Enter customer name to search records:");
customername=sc.nextLine();
if (customername.equals(cname))
{       
    System.out.println("Customer name:"+cname);
    System.out.println("Customer address:"+caddress);
    System.out.println("Customer phone:"+cphone);            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.The problem is solved now.ok thanks

Comment: You want to really know how to compare strings, to avoid copying such obviously bad code into your answer!

Comment: Yes i accept your answer because i got solution from your answer.thanks

Comment: I was just focusing on initializing the strings I did not see that. Thank you for pointing it out. Edited.

Comment: And when updating your answer, why not fix the whole if block to be less nonsensical?